# Raspberry Pi 4 NAS setup with RAID0 (for Remote Access)

Tags: nextcloud, raid

I'm trying to setup a NAS server using my RaspberryPi 4 with two 2TB HDD's in a RAID0 configuration. I would like to have remote access from various other devices (Android phone, linux desktop, windows laptop). Initially I set this up with NextCloud and had everything working great (using RAID0 and remote access using port forwarding with a DNS service). The issue was that I could not get it to use the RAID0 Drive as the primary storage (I could only add it as external storage, but files were saved to the SD card by default). Therefore, I was wondering:

1) Is there a way to configure nextcloud to use a RAID0 drive as the root save folder?

2) Is there another NAS software that is compatible with Raspberry Pi that I could use for this purpose (e.g. has RAID0 compatibility and can be configured for remote access outside of LAN)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remote access and drive configuration are completely separate things. You basically have three questions. 1a. How to setup raid0. 1b. Can you use this raid array as the root (pretty sure you won't be able to do that) and 2. how to open the pi up to external access

Comment: Yes they are different but the second part of the question is if there is a software that has the remote access and drive configuration capabilities that I'm looking for. I know how to setup RAID0 and how to set up rpi for external access. I'm looking for something that will let me do both as I described.